BCF tool on 1000 genome 30x data
I've been using BCF tools to extract 1000 genome data from chromosome files (to get the genptype of the variants located at certain positions in the 2504 samples of the 1000 genome data).
I've been trying bcftools on the data from the 1000 genome with 30x coverage and I don't any output.
Anybody has an idea of how to get this data?
Thanks!
Marianne
No getting output data

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
